# Is there a quotient map between arbitrary topological spaces?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces.

If there is a quotient map $p:X\rightarrow Y$, then the topology on $Y$ is completely determined by $p$.

I'm curious whether the converse holds.

That is, if we know all informations about the space $Y$, can we determine a quotient map between $p:X\rightarrow Y$?

That is, given any topological spaces $X,Y$ such that $|X|≧|Y|$, does there exist a quotient map $p:X\rightarrow Y$?

Comment: Of course not. The quotient is surjective, so if $|X|<|Y|$, then no quotient mapping $X\to Y$ can exist. If you refine your question somewhat perhaps a more interesting answer will emerge.

Comment: To answer the question in the title, no. In particular, any quotient map $p: X \to Y$ is surjective, and so we must have $\text{card } X \geq \text{card } Y$. This condition is, however, certainly not sufficient.

Comment: @IttayWeiss I just edited :)

Comment: Still obviously not. Cardinality of the underlying sets is not enough as there is also an obvious cardinality relation between the topologies themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the following. If $X$ is connected (or compact, or countably compact, or separable) and $Y$ is not then there is no continuous (and hence no quotient) map from $X$ onto $Y$. There also should be other topological properties which are preserved by quotient maps. For instance, sequentiality.